# Just-recorded macro fails to execute - AdvancedFilter method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am working with Microsoft Office 2010.

I want to create a button that refreshes an 'AdvancedFilter' upon click.
What I did is to record a macro in order to replay my actions.
But the macro fails already at its first execution.

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Macro
'

Workbooks("requirement_spec.xls") _
    .Sheets("Requirements").Range("A4:BU279").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("A1:F5"), _
        CopyToRange:=Range("A11:BU11"), _
        Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Starting the macro via Excel's macro menu or via a button results in this error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   AdvancedFilter method of Range class failed

I didn't change a character of the automatically recorded macro when producing the error message.
(I just did some line-breaking changes for SO)

Comment: Change this  `CopyToRange:=Range("A11:BU11")` to `CopyToRange:=Range("A11")` and see if it works.

Comment: It doesn't help, the error stays where it is...

Comment: Nippey : When you recorded the macro, did the filter worked ?

Comment: I believe the filter is in another workbook as the question has a tag excel-2010 where as you are trying to do filter in `Workbooks("requirement_spec.xls")` which is excel 2003 version. Kindly Activate the workbook before doing filter using this syntax `Workbook("requirement_spec.xls").Activate`. Also make sure the `Sheets("Requirements")` exist in `Workbook("requirement_spec.xls")`

Comment: @Santosh: It works while recording. Activating has no effect. But I found that assigning `Range("A1:F5")` to a variable leads to the Variable content `Nothing`. I have to investigate that..

Comment: Expanded the `Range()` to `ActiveSheet.Range()` with no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into something similar today with Excel 2013. Coming here, I noticed the old question with no real solution.

What I found out, is that the error does not appear when a range in the sheet with the filter is being selected. Therefore, the following worked for me:

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Macro
'
Dim wb As Workbook, wbSave As Workbook, _
    ws As Worksheet, wsSave As Worksheet, rSel As Range
'don't annoy users with changing the selection
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'save old selection values to be sure
Set wbSave = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSave = ActiveSheet
Set rSel = Selection
'activate target workbook + select something
'in my case it's a sheet in the same test workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("requirement_spec.xls")
wb.Activate
Sheets("Filter").Select
Range("A11").Select
'apply filter now    
Sheets("Requirements").Range("A4:BU279").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("A1:F5"), CopyToRange:=Range("A11"), Unique:=False
'restore old selection to be sure
wbSave.Activate
wsSave.Activate
rSel.Select
'allow screen updating again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
Workbooks("requirement_spec.xls") _
    .Sheets("Requirements").Range("A4:BU279").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("A1:F5"), _
        CopyToRange:=Range("A11"), _
        Unique:=False
End Sub
```

so you're hoping that from 275 rows with about 50 columns (A4 to BU 279) will be copied to the **same worksheet Range("A11") ?**

Comment: That's what Excel hopes :) But it doen't help, the error stays.